# How to link the JGraph sensor and Java mail?

Tags: java, netbeans, arduino

I have problem a to link the jgraph and the java mail. The program is about, if the temperature is more than 60 Celsius, the program will send alert to my email. The problem is, I don't know how to call the data temperature that captured.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){

if(connectButton.getText().equals("Connect")){

       **//attempt to connect the serial port**
        choosenPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(portlist.getSelectedItem().toString());
        choosenPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);

        if(choosenPort.openPort()){
            connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
            portlist.setEnabled(false);
        }
        **//create a new thread that listen for incoming text and populates the graph**

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(choosenPort.getInputStream());
                int x = 0;
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    try{
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    int number =Integer.parseInt(line);
                    series.add(x++, number * 0.488);
                    window.repaint();

                    **// mail sent to the owner**

                    if(x> 50){

                        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        final String user = "xxxxx.gmail.com";
                        final String pass = "xxxxxxx";
                        String to = "xxxx.gmail.com";
                        String from = "xxxx.gmail.com";
                        String subject ="Smart Alarm Emergency";
                        String messageText ="this is try message";
                        boolean sessionDebug = false;

                        Properties props = new Properties();

                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

                        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

                        Session mailSession =Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
                        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
                        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(to));
                        InternetAddress[] address ={ new InternetAddress(to)};

                        msg.setRecipients (Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                        msg.setSubject(subject);
                        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                        msg.setText(messageText);

                        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
                        transport.connect(host, user, pass);
                        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                        transport.close();

                        System.out.println("Sent Succesfully");


                    }else{

                    }


                }catch (Exception e){
                        }
                        }
                scanner.close();  
            }
        };
        thread.start();                         

    }else{
        //attempt to disconnect the serial port
        choosenPort.closePort();
        portlist.setEnabled(true);
        connectButton.setText("Connect");
        series.clear();

    }

}

});
```

Comment: That empty `else{}` statement is useless.

Comment: @DonaldDuck i forgot to rid that, tq

Comment: Also, is this Javascript or Java? The title suggests it's Java and the tag suggests it's Javascript. Javascript and Java are two completely different languages. If it's Java (which it probably is since it doesn't look like any Javascript I know), please [edit] to retag it accordingly.

Comment: @DonaldDuck done mate , sorry 